# IIS 6 permanent redirect to deal with a google indexing issue

Tags: iis-6, google, seo

My company changed domain names about an year ago. When searching for the company name, Google still displays the old url (for the purpose of this post, oldsite.com)

I have used IIS 6 to set up a permanent redirect to newsite.com at that address, using the following settings:

```
Content for this resource should come from: A redirection to a URL

Redirect to [http://www.newsite.com]

A permanent redirection for this resource
```

Is there anything I am missing? Is there a way to remove the old URL from the results?

I know this is an SEO-related question but I think it is a technical one and not about improving/manipulating rankings...

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The permanent redirection is the key, so if you recently did that you're probably set.  The Google bots will notice the redirection and make sure to index the new location now instead.  I suspect you'll notice the change within days.  Hopefully you have it set so that it carries through the path and querystring so that old pages redirect to their equivalent on the new domain.

If you want to remove the old domain name quicker you can use these tools of Google's: http://www.google.com/webmasters/tools.

Comment: The permanent redirection has been there for a over a month so I am a little concerned... An additional step we are taking is changing the url for our company in the dmoz.org open directory.

Comment: Try a manual test of the page that you notice in google to make sure that it redirects as expected.  Use something like firefox+firebug to confirm that it really is giving a 301 redirect and not some other type of redirect.  If it's all correct then try manually using the tools in the link above.  It may just need a nudge.